# Angular2: issue injecting Http into service

Tags: service, dependency-injection, angular

I am using angular2 and have encountered problem when injecting `Http` into another service.

Here is my `boot.ts` file:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { provide } from 'angular2/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { appInjector } from './app-injector';
import { LoginService } from './services/login.service';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from 'angular2/http';
import { RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LoginService, provide(
        LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
        )] 
    ).then((appRef) => {
  // store a reference to the injector
  appInjector(appRef.injector);

});
```

Here is my `app.component.ts` file:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {LoginService} from './services/login.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/app.tpl.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [LoginService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private _loginService: LoginService) { }


    login() {
        this._loginService.login();
    }
}
```

And here is the offending `login.service.ts` file:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http,Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()

export class LoginService{

    http: Http;

    constructor(_http: Http) { 
        this.http = _http;
    }

    login(){
        // do sth
    }
}
```

The issue is with the `constructor` in `login.service.ts` file.

When I remove the parameters in constructor (leaving `constructor(){}`) the page renders all right. When I keep the `Http` parameter, the page does not render and instead in browser console I see: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error.

I need to inject `Http` into my `LoginService`, but I could not find what is the issue. I have looked into some blogs and SO questions, i.e. [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html), but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you forgot to add the http.dev.js file into your HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

It should be the cause of your error: "unexpected token <".

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

You're using Http module in two files but the HTTP_PROVIDERS import is only in component. Delete it from component and add to your boot file.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LoginService, provide(
        LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
        )] 
    ).then((appRef) => {
  // store a reference to the injector
  appInjector(appRef.injector);

});
```